# Calculating customer lifetime using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm performing a Cohort analysis using python, and I am having trouble creating a new column that sums up the total months a user has stayed with us.

I know the math behind the answer, all I have to do is:

1. subtract the year when they canceled our service from when they started it
2. Multiply that by 12.
3. Subtract the month when they canceled our service from when they started it.
4. Add those two numbers together.

So in Excel, it looks like this:

=(YEAR(C2)-YEAR(B2))*12+(MONTH(C2)-MONTH(B2))

C is when the customer canceled the date, and B is when they started

The problem is that I am very new to Python and Pandas, and I am having trouble translating that function in Python

What I have tried so far:

```
df['Lifetime'] = df.Plan_Cancel_Date('%Y') - df.Plan_Start_Date('%Y')*12 + 
df.Plan_Cancel_Date('%m') - df.Plan_Start_Date('%m')
df.head()
```

It returns with an error 'Series' is not callable, and I have a general understanding of what that means.

I then tried:

```
def LTVCalc (Plan_Start_Date, Plan_Cancel_Date):
    df['Lifetime'] = df.Plan_Cancel_Date('%Y') - df.Plan_Start_Date('%Y')*12 + 
    df.Plan_Cancel_Date('%m') - df.Plan_Start_Date('%m')
df.head()
```

But that didn't add the Column 'Lifetime' to the DataFrame.

Anyone able to help a rookie?

Comment: What is the dtype of `Plan_Cancel_Date` (`df.Plan_Cancel_Date.dtype`)? If it's not datetime then I would convert it to a datetime. 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need first convert [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then use [`dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and
[`dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Plan_Cancel_Date': ['2018-07-07','2019-03-05','2020-10-08'],
    'Plan_Start_Date': ['2016-02-07','2017-01-05','2017-08-08']
})
#print (df)

#if necessary convert to datetimes
df.Plan_Start_Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Plan_Start_Date)
df.Plan_Cancel_Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Plan_Cancel_Date)

df['Lifetime'] = ((df.Plan_Cancel_Date.dt.year - df.Plan_Start_Date.dt.year)*12 + 
                   df.Plan_Cancel_Date.dt.month - df.Plan_Start_Date.dt.month)

print (df)

  Plan_Cancel_Date Plan_Start_Date  Lifetime
0       2018-07-07      2016-02-07        29
1       2019-03-05      2017-01-05        26
2       2020-10-08      2017-08-08        38
```